# Breakpoint failed to bind error when debugging .NET framework code?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols

I'm trying to debug System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml and related classes in Visual Studio 2015, but I consistently see lines in the core framework code being skipped while stepping through in the debugger. Unfortunately, the lines that are skipped include the lines I need to debug.

Has anyone run into similar issues, or gotten this to work properly?

I followed the directions on [the Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx). Could this be because the wrong version is loading, or because of some optimizations under the hood that I am unable to disable?

When I try to set breakpoints on lines that are skipped during debugging, I get an error stating that the breakpoint failed to bind.

Any help or tips would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is resolved now - I had to turn off JIT optimizations in Visual Studio 2015, since the core .NET libraries are released with optimizations.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/08/14/debugging-optimized-code/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution here, you could mark it as answer.

Comment: I will in 42 minutes from the time of this posting, when Stack Overflow will allow me to :)